# MSTeams Bot working in webchat test but not working in msteams

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to build a basic bot with **Microsoft Azure Bot Service**. I have created a WebApp Bot in the Bot Service using **Nodejs** **EchoBot sample**. It is successfully deployed and works as expected in the test web chat but when i try to add it to MSTeams using App Studio to create a manifest and side loading the bot, the message sending to the bot is failing. Also,I cannot add the bot to a team it displays a dialog box saying **"something went wrong"** without any further information.

[image]

[image]

[image]
I have also tried the sample of **bot builder** for **nodejs** and deployed using **ngrok**, exactly same error for both. I have also tried with different accounts, with subscription, with free account all same issue.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please add Teams as a channel for your bot? You can do that by going to channels section of your bot in the azure portal.

Comment: Also if you open the build blade in the Bot Service, you can see the onTurnError in the console there. Doesn't always give a lot of information but might be enough to identify the root issue.